# What's the difference between array and Object(array)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the MDN reduce [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) , I find such code in `reduce` polyfill:

```js
// 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      var o = Object(this);
```

I do a simply test, and it return `true`.

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(a === Object(a))
```

What's the difference between the two and why is it used here?

Comment: Well `reduce` is not necessary called on an array, that's why. It also would work on strings for example.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I probable knew what it means...

Comment: reduce also can be used such as `Array.prototype.reduce.call('123', (acc, curr) => { console.log(curr) }, 0)`

Comment: @Bergi no question left, thanks.